# image_picker plugin causes build error for Android

Tags: flutter

I installed the image_picker plugin into my project, and it works with iOS, But now the Android build crashes with the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

Any idea why the Android build crashes when using this plugin?

Comment: Changes in file `app\build.gradle`

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

...

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}`

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `multidex` in your `build.gradle` file :

```
android {
.
.
. 
  defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion  //your minimum SDK version
         targetSdkVersion //your target SDK version


         multiDexEnabled true // this is what you should add
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Enabling multidex fixed an ealier issue I encountered with Firebase plugins, but it was already enabled when I faced the current issue. I have posted the solution that worked

Answer (score 1):

I had to roll back my Firestore plugin to 0.7.4 to fix this: answer [found here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23929).

I do also have multidex enabled as other answers suggested -  this fixed an earlier crash I encountered with Firebase plugins.